# Disable design-time instantiation of bindings in Blend

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, blend

When I bind data collections through the `Window.DataContext` and I have a lot of items in those collections (thousands), my memory simply gets eaten up to the point where it's frustrating.  Those collections are instantiated during design time and get displayed while I'm working on the application.  I couldn't find an option to disable that feature.  While it's nice on other projects, it's handicapping me at the moment.

Does anyone know how to disable it?

Comment: Could you not do a mock up Collection in your xaml with let's say 2 or 3 items? Of course if the items don't have like 100 properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try set the DataContext via [`d:DesignInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd490796%28VS.100%29.aspx) with `IsDesignTimeCreatable=False`:

> Use `d:DesignInstance` for create data bindings at design time for a DataContext that is assigned at run time. To create the data binding, you use the data binding builder to create a special design-time data context and set the DesignInstance to a business object type. DesignInstance is a design-time property.

Example:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:Person />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:Person, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}">
    <TextBox Width="100" 
             Height="30" 
             Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
</Grid>
```

In this case, DataContext will not be created in design mode and Text of `TextBox` will be empty.